# Is the customer supposed to receive an email when the order is voided?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, customer, email

I had problems with my customers receiving emails. I'm now testing a fix I found and it seems to be working so far.

I am new to Magento which is why I don't know the answer to this question: is the customer supposed to receive an email when I void the order through the Admin panel?

I looked through the docs and through StackExchange and couldn't find the answer. Maybe I wasn't typing in the right keywords.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Magento will not automatically send cancellation e-mails. However, you can manually send them from the admin by navigating into the order then send an order comment which will trigger the "Order Update (for Guest)" e-mail with the "canceled" order status and any comments as shown below:

[image: Order Comments]

If you want these e-mail to send automatically on order cancel, you can write custom code to observe the `order_cancel_after` event and trigger the "Order Update (for Guest)" e-mail to send automatically.